# jQuery removeAttr('style') not working in Firefox & Safari

Tags: jquery, css, image, firefox, safari

I've made an upload image function and I'm determining the dimensions of the image with jQuery so that when the image is uploaded it will fit into it's containing div. When the image is detected jQuery applies some CSS to make it fit in the div and then center it properly, all depending if the image is rectangular, square, etc... There's also a remove button. The problem is that if I upload an image, remove it and then upload another, the CSS used for the prior image applies to the current one, making it look weird in Firefox and Safari.

My question is: Is there any way to completely remove the styles from the prior image so that the next uploaded image can be recalculated? I added `$('#logoPreview').removeAttr('style');`
 to the remove button click function and the style attr is actually removed in the HTML, but if you inspect the element, the styles remain and are applied to the next uploaded image. Works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox or Safari.

Any suggestions??

Thanks beforehand!

Here's the code:

```
// Visualize logo
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#logoPreview').attr('src', e.target.result);

        $('#logoPreviewWrapper').css('display', 'block');
        $('span.button.upload').css('display', 'none');
        $('span.button.remove').css('display', 'block');
        $('idTwo input').css('display', 'none');

        var wLogo = $('#logoPreview').width();
        var hLogo = $('#logoPreview').height();

        // Position & resize square images
        if ( wLogo == hLogo ) {
            $('#logoPreview').css('height', '52px');
            $('#logoPreview').css('width', 'auto');

            var wLogoResize = $('#logoPreview').width();

            $('#logoPreview').css('marginTop', '-26px');
            $('#logoPreview').css('marginLeft', -wLogoResize/2);
        }

        // Position & resize horizontal rectangular images
        if ( wLogo > hLogo ) {
            $('#logoPreview').css('width', '154px');
            $('#logoPreview').css('height', 'auto');

            var hLogoResize = $('#logoPreviewWrapper img').height();

            $('#logoPreview').css('marginTop', -hLogoResize/2);
            $('#logoPreview').css('marginLeft', '-77px');
        }

        // Position & resize vertical rectanglular images
        if ( wLogo < hLogo ) {
            $('#logoPreview').css('height', '52px');
            $('#logoPreview').css('width', 'auto');

            var wLogoResize = $('#logoPreviewWrapper img').width();

            $('#logoPreview').css('marginTop', '-26px');
            $('#logoPreview').css('marginLeft', -wLogoResize/2);
        }
     };

     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$('.idTwo input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});

// The Remove Button
$('span.button.remove').click(function() {
  $('#logoPreview').removeAttr('style');

  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $('input[type="number"]').val(1);
  $('#logoPreviewWrapper').css('display', 'none');

  $('.idTwo input').attr('value', '');

  $('span.button.upload').css('display', 'block');
  $('.quantity.buttons_added input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', false);
  $('input[value="-"]').prop('disabled', false);
   updateValues();
});
```

Comment: try with `removeProp('style')` as `removeAttr()` deprecated after jquery 1.6

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bhushan. Still not working. I'm using v1.10.2. when I replace removeAttr with removeProp it stops working in Chrome.

Comment: [.removeAttr() is not deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and it works for me (FF 33, Safari 5.1.7, jQ 1.11.1). But you can try `$elem.attr('style', null)` which has same result.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

Turns out that the order in which Chrome and Firefox 'read' this code is not the same. Chrome does it from top to bottom and in Firefox it's all asynchronous so this:

```
$('#logoPreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
```

In Firefox is happening after I get the width of the uploaded image. here's how I solved it. The solution was to start doing ifs after that image has loaded,and the `removeAttr(''style)` is not even necessary in the remove button, like so:

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
        var logoPreview = $('#logoPreview');
        logoPreview.attr('src', e.target.result);

        logoPreview.on('load', function() {
          $('#logoPreviewWrapper').css('display', 'block');
          $('span.button.upload').css('display', 'none');
          $('span.button.remove').css('display', 'block');
          $('idTwo input').css('display', 'none');

          var wLogo = logoPreview.width();
          var hLogo = logoPreview.height();

          // Position & resize square images
          if ( wLogo == hLogo ) {
              logoPreview.css('height', '52px');
              logoPreview.css('width', 'auto');

              var wLogoResize = logoPreview.width();

              logoPreview.css('marginTop', '-26px');
              logoPreview.css('marginLeft', -wLogoResize/2);
          }

          // Position & resize horizontal rectangular images
          if ( wLogo > hLogo ) {
              logoPreview.css('width', '154px');
              logoPreview.css('height', 'auto');

              var hLogoResize = $('#logoPreviewWrapper img').height();

              logoPreview.css('marginTop', -hLogoResize/2);
              logoPreview.css('marginLeft', '-77px');
          }

          // Position & resize vertical rectanglular images
          if ( wLogo < hLogo ) {
              logoPreview.css('height', '52px');
              logoPreview.css('width', 'auto');

              var wLogoResize = $('#logoPreviewWrapper img').width();

              logoPreview.css('marginTop', '-26px');
              logoPreview.css('marginLeft', -wLogoResize/2);
          }
        });
     };

     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$('.idTwo input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});

// The Remove Button
$('span.button.remove').click(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $('input[type="number"]').val(1);
  $('#logoPreviewWrapper').css('display', 'none');

  $('.idTwo input').attr('value', '');

  $('span.button.upload').css('display', 'block');
  $('.quantity.buttons_added input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', false);
  $('input[value="-"]').prop('disabled', false);
   updateValues();
});
```

Thanks anyway!! :D